# How to use a primary constructor with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been reading the introductory guide for primary constructors in c#12 and I'm getting some unexpected results (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors).

I have some code like:

```
public class ServiceA(IServiceB service)
{
    public async Task<bool> Method() {
        return await service.GetValue();
    }
}
```

Now, if I create a unit test like this:

```
[Fact]
public void Test1() {
    var mockB = Substitute.For<IServiceB>();
    _sut = new SeviceA(mockB);
    _sut.Method();
    Assert.NotNull(mockB);
}
```

In the call to `_sut.Method();`, inside, the `service` that is provided in the test via a mock, it's actually `null` in ServiceA.Method. The mock is correctly created in the unit test, but it doesn't make it to the method.

A way I found to solve this is by creating a property or field to capture the Primary constructor parameter and then use that instead of the parameter. Something like this:

```
public class ServiceA(IServiceB service)
{
    private IServiceB ServiceProperty { get; } = service; //capture the parameter
    public async Task<bool> Method() {
        return await ServiceProperty.GetValue(); //use property instead of parameter
    }
}
```

As I said, the above now works, however from what I understand from the docs, that parameter capturing should not be necessary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors#dependency-injection

> Another common use for primary constructors is to specify parameters for dependency injection. The following code creates a simple controller that requires a service interface for its use:
> C#

```
 public interface IService
 {
     Distance GetDistance();
 }
 public class ExampleController(IService service) : ControllerBase
 {
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult<Distance> Get()
     {
         return service.GetDistance();
     }
}
```

> The primary constructor clearly indicates the parameters needed in the class. You use the primary constructor parameters as you would any other variable in the class.

-> Am I misunderstanding Primary constructors?

Comment: Is this the actual code?

Comment: Was not able to repro - [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Y84Xk)

Comment: That is not the actual code. I see it working in the fiddle. Maybe it's something related to xunit and running it via unit test instead of Main? When I was debugging the code and reached service.GetValue() that's when I saw that `service` is null.

Comment: Having the same problem here, I tried making a reproduction solution but that somehow doesn't have the problem. Did you found out more?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I removed Primary constructors for now until I have more time to investigate.

Comment: Same problem here, I have a single service that for some reason is always resolved as null when using primary constructors, replace them with a normal constructor and everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve it for everyone but it solved it for me.

The problem was actually that I needed more Primary Constructors.

Some of the injected services didn't have Primary Constructors so I tested adding the constructors to my service implementations and after that it started working as expected.

I still think it should work without that but now it works even without capturing the parameters.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Edit: Just and FYI the parameters still show null in the debugger, but they work at runtime for some reason.