# Primary Constructor Parameter not Working in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, rider

Problem Statement:

Generally, we write asp.net unit tests for Service layer:
Service.cs

```
public class AppService : IAppService
{
  private readonly IAppRepository _appRepository;
  public AppService(IAppRepository appRepository) 
  {
    this._appRepository = appRepository;
  }

  public App Get(int id) 
  {
    // some logic code here
    return _appRepository.Get(it);
  }
}
```

Unit Tests (xUnit + Substitute)AppServiceTests.cs

```
public class AppServiceTests
{
  public void test()
  {
    IAppRepository mockAppRepository = Substitute.For<IAppRepository>();
    // some mock logic here;
    AppService service = new AppService(mockAppRepository)
    // Assertion
  }
}
```

So, above code works well. This is a general way we use before.

Now, I create a new Project with .NET 8 with C# 12.

When I tried same implement,  I got a tips from Rider(Jetbrains) IDE,
It can use follwing way(named **Primary Constructor Parameter**), the code is

AppService.cs

```
public class AppService(IAppRepository appRepository) : IAppService
{
  // no private field need any more
  public App Get(int id)
  {
    return appRepository.Get(id);
  }
}
```

the unit test code is same with before.

However, I debug the unit test code, I got a null appRepository in Get() method. But it works in actual runtime instead of testing.
So I don't understand why these two implements got different result when injected repository object in unit test.

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but it seems like you are not the only one experiencing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528963/how-to-use-a-primary-constructor-with-dependency-injection

Comment: @AstridE.  you are right, I reviewed that question, it should be same one. Thanks for provide it, will keep follwoing up this question. not sure if it is a xunit problem.